# How to find a quotient group?

Tags: algebra, group-theory

Given a normal subgroup H of a (large, finite permutation) group G, knowing a set of generators for each of H and G, how to find a subgroup K of G that is isomorphic to G/H? (Using Mathematica.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: For what sort of groups and how are they presented (in *Mathematica*)?  BTW, it's not true in general.  E.g. the additive reals modulo integers is isomorphic to the circle group, but the circle group is not isomorphic to a subgroup of the real numbers.

Comment: The problem is when the order of the group is very large, so listing the elements of the group is not possible. Patrick's answer requires listing all the elements of the group. Also, GroupElements requires two arguments.

Comment: To quote the docs: "`GroupElements[group]` returns the list of all elements of `group`." I agree that it's a horrible way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. I was just quoting the error message I got from Mathematica.

Comment: I've added my take using MMA's clunky group theory functionality (and curated data), but of course this suffers from the same problem as @PatrickStevens' answer of listing all of the group elements. Have you done any google searches for MMA group presentations or something? It seems like there's stuff out there, but I'm suitably far-removed from my college group theory classes to decide whether they're useful or not.

Comment: Thanks, march, for helping by showing some code. The second line "q===..." returned False. I didn't know how to fix it. The "factorGroupCayley..." line gave me only error messages. I don't have the "SubsetQ" so I replaced it with an obvious "subsetQ[big_,small_]:=" I wrote, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: I think it should work now. See the updated answer. I did some copy-and-pasting and some typing-in, and apparently I forgot some stuff when typing-in. I added my version of a `subsetQ`, so all you need to do is replace `SubsetQ` with `subsetQ` in the code.

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, please check the grey check-mark sign next to that answer!

Answer (score 8):

The following is a hacky way of doing it for finite groups only:

```
quotientGroup[g_, h_] := 
 RightCosetRepresentative[h, #] & /@ GroupElements[g] // 
 DeleteDuplicates
```

Comment: It's been along time since my group theory days. This generates the factor group; is it necessarily isomorphic to a subgroup of the original group?

Comment: @march If it's not, then the OP is asking for something which doesn't exist. It is indeed not always possible: consider the quaternion group $Q_8$ with generators $\langle i, j, k \rangle$ quotiented by the normal subgroup $\{1, -1\}$. This is isomorphic to $V_4$, which is not a subgroup of the quaternion group because any single non-$\pm 1$ element generates a cyclic 4-group.

Comment: Good, thanks. That's vaguely what I remembered. I suppose one could directly check whether or not the output of your code is a subset (and therefore necessarily a subgroup) of the original group (by using `SubsetQ`), which would completely answer OP's question.

Comment: In the Q8 example, my code results in a group of order 384 as the "factor group". I'm decidedly confused.

Comment: q = PermutationGroup[
   Cycles@*List /@ FiniteGroupData["Quaternion", "Cycles"]];
h = PermutationGroup[
   Cycles@*List /@ 
    Select[FiniteGroupData["Quaternion", "Cycles"], 
     Length[#] <= 2 &]]; RightCosetRepresentative[h, #] & /@ GroupElements[q] // 
   DeleteDuplicates // PermutationGroup // GroupOrder

Comment: Maybe there elements that are represented in different ways in cycle notation. Maybe you can reduce them all to transpositions, then `DeleteDuplicates` or something. Edit: oh, but the help files on `Cycles` say that they automatically reduce to canonical form, so...

Comment: In the definition of `q`, you are forming the `PermutationGroup` *generated* by the `Cycles` that show up in your list, so `GroupOrder[q] == 384`, meaning that it's not actually the Quaternions. Edit: or maybe not. Something weird is going on.

Comment: Upshot: Mathematica makes it hard to do group theory.

Comment: You need to check the subgroup `h` is [normal or not](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268236/21532) firstly

Comment: @yode By hypothesis the subgroup was normal.

Answer (score 6):

Extending `Patrick Stevens` answer and modifying it somewhat. As an example, I'll use the [`Quaternion`s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) `{1, -1, i, -i, j, -j, k, -k}` (per our discussion in the comments to his answer) and factor by the normal subgroup `{-1, 1}`.

*Warning: if the groups are too big, the following calculations will probably take too much time*.

To extract a permutation-group representation of the group, we do

```
q = PermutationCycles /@ FiniteGroupData["Quaternion", "PermutationRepresentation"] // Sort
(* {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 7, 8}}]
     , Cycles[{{1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 8, 6, 4}}]
     , Cycles[{{1, 4, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 7}}]
     , Cycles[{{1, 6, 5, 2}, {3, 8, 7, 4}}]
     , Cycles[{{1, 7, 5, 3}, {2, 4, 6, 8}}]
     , Cycles[{{1, 8, 5, 4}, {2, 7, 6, 3}}]
     , Cycles[{{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}}]} *)
```

We can verify that this set is closed under group multiplication by doing

```
q === Sort@Union@Flatten@Outer[PermutationProduct, q, q]
(* True *)
```

The subgroup `{-1, 1}` can be picked out using

```
h = {First@q, Last@q}
(* {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}}]} *)
```

We construct the right-cosets of `h` using

```
cosets = Sort /@ Outer[PermutationProduct, q, h] // DeleteDuplicates;
cosets // TableForm
(* Cycles[{}]                       Cycles[{{1,5},{2,6},{3,7},{4,8}}]
   Cycles[{{1,2,5,6},{3,4,7,8}}]    Cycles[{{1,6,5,2},{3,8,7,4}}]
   Cycles[{{1,3,5,7},{2,8,6,4}}]    Cycles[{{1,7,5,3},{2,4,6,8}}]
   Cycles[{{1,4,5,8},{2,3,6,7}}]    Cycles[{{1,8,5,4},{2,7,6,3}}] *)
```

and we will use

```
cosetReps = cosets[[All, 1]]
```

(the first column above) as our set of right-coset representatives.

Finally, we construct a (clunky) multiplication for cosets via

```
factorGroupMultiply[elements__List, cosetReps_] /; SubsetQ[cosetsReps, elements] := 
 First@@Select[cosets, MemberQ[#, PermutationProduct @@ elements] &]
```

(Pre-MMA-v.10, you can use a (again clunky) homebrew `subsetQ`,

```
subsetQ[list1_, list2_] := Sort@Intersection[list1, list2] === Sort@Union@list2
```

which is not well, tested, but should work.) This multiplication function will accept members of `cosetReps`, multiply them using `PermutationProduct`, find in which coset the result lives, then return the corresponding coset representative.

To visualize the resulting group, let's form the Cayley table:

```
factorGroupCayley = Outer[factorGroupMultiply[{##}, cosetReps] &, cosetReps, cosetReps];
factorGroupCayley /. Thread[cosetReps -> {1, 2, 3, 4}] // TableForm
(* 1   2   3   4
   2   1   4   3
   3   4   1   2
   4   3   2   1 *)
```

Finally, we can decide whether or not this group is isomorphic to a subgroup of the original group by extracting the subgroup data for the group:

```
subgroups = FiniteGroupData["Quaternion", "Subgroups"]
(* {"Trivial", {"CyclicGroup", 2}, {"CyclicGroup", 4}, "Quaternion"} *)
```

The only subgroup of order 4 is cyclic, and the Cayley table above is clearly not the Cayley table of a cyclic group. In general, we might go through the process of finding the Cayley tables for each of the subgroups using

```
subGroupCayleyTables = FiniteGroupData[#, "MultiplicationTable"] & /@ subgroups;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Patrick and march for your ideas about looking at the quaternion group.

> FiniteGroupData["Quaternion", "Subgroups"]
>   {"Trivial", {"CyclicGroup", 2}, {"CyclicGroup", 4}, "Quaternion"}.

The quotient group march mentions is clearly not cyclic but does have order 4, and there are only 2 of those, and the other is not a subgroup of the quaternion group.

> FiniteGroupData[4]
>   {{"CyclicGroup", 4}, {"AbelianGroup", {2, 2}}}.

This quotient group goes by several names.

> FiniteGroupData[{"AbelianGroup", {2, 2}}, "IsomorphicGroups"]
>   {"Vierergruppe", {4, 2}, {"CrystallographicPointGroup", 5}, 
>   {"CrystallographicPointGroup",  6}, {"CrystallographicPointGroup", 7}, {"CyclicGroupUnits", 8}, {"CyclicGroupUnits", 12}, {"DihedralGroup", 2}}.

So the answer to my question is that, generally speaking, there isn't necessarily a subgroup isomorphic to a quotient group. I have learned a lot talking with you.