# How to determine if a group H is a normal subgroup of group G?

Tags: group-theory

A subgroup $H$ of the group $G$ is normal group in $G$ if and only if $\displaystyle ghg^{-1}\in H$ for all $\displaystyle g\in G$ and $\displaystyle h\in H$. How to use *MMA* to know the group $H$ is a normal group of group $G$? Such as:

```
G = SymmetricGroup[6];
H = AlternatingGroup[6];
```

Comment: `g = GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[6]];
h = GroupElements[AlternatingGroup[6]];
conj[x_] := PermutationProduct[#, x, InversePermutation[#]] & /@ g`  Brute fprcing: `Union[Flatten[conj /@ h]] == Sort[h]` yields `True`

Comment: @ubpdqn Yes, I note your solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267933/21532). But `RandomSample[Sort[GroupElements[AlternatingGroup[6]]]]===GroupElements[AlternatingGroup[6]]` will return `False`. You need a parameter `Less` like my answer in following. And I use the `PermutationReplace` to get the conjugate is more concise than yours. :)

Comment: Not sure I understand but I'll accept your point

Comment: @ubpdqn I've just updated the very efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IsNormalQ[H_, G_] := Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Catenate[
     Outer[PermutationReplace, GroupElements[H], 
      Complement[GroupElements[G], GroupElements[H]]]]], Less] === GroupElements[H]
```

Or little concise, but sometimes it will be slower:

```
IsNormalQ[H_, G_] := ContainsExactly[
  Catenate[Outer[PermutationReplace, GroupElements[H], 
    Complement[GroupElements[G], GroupElements[H]]]],GroupElements[H]]
```

## Update(Simplicity and efficiency)

```
IsNormalQ[H_,G_]:=AllTrue[GroupElements[G],PermutationReplace[H,#]==H&]
```